# Saving form data from a custom WooCommerce My Account tab

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have created a new Member Details tab in My Account and populated the tab with form fields to gather member details like hobbies, birthday, etc. These details are then displayed on the My Account Dashboard.

How can I save the data that is submitted on the new Member Details tab?

Many sites have examples how to display info on new tabs but I couldn't find any that show how to submit and save form data.

```
function add_custom_fields() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
    <form id="edit_member_details" method="post">
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="member_hobbies"><?php _e( 'Member Hobbies', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="member_hobbies" id="member_hobbies" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->member_hobbies ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="button" name="save_member_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save member details', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save member details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="woocommerce_edit_member_details" value="save_member_details" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_member_details', 12, 1 );
function save_member_details( $user_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['member_hobbies'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'member_hobbies', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['member_hobbies'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Woocommerce does their form submission handling is by creating classes which are then hooked into either the `wp` or `template_redirect` actions. You can see this for yourself by looking at [WC_Form_Handler](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Form_Handler.html#10-1131).

Depending on your approach, you can follow a similar strategy and create a class or function that is hooked early to process your form data. For example

```
add_action('wp', 'my_form_handler');
function my_form_handler() {
   // read in my post data

   // process my data.

   // optionally redirect
}
```

One issue that you'll run into here is that this hook will run every time `wp` or `template_redirect` is called, which is every single page load. Woocommerce handles this by looking for nonces, post fields, and using the is_* functions. One strategy I use is to begin my function with

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
```

This will cause the function to exit out if we're not detecting a POST action on page.

If you decide to perform form validation, you'll run into issues with reporting errors if you opt to use `wc_add_notice`, especially if you decide to redirect after form processing. If you do redirect after using `wc_add_notice`, your notice will be lost, as notices do not persist across page loads.

Comment: Using your framework I am still unable to save the data. I'm sure I am missing pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: Are you able to post what you used?

Comment: I was able to get this working but I'm trying to make sure it only runs when 1) On an account page 2) only when a form is posted and 3) when on the custom endpoint. I can test for the account page with is_account_page() and if posted with the code you provided but is_wc_endpoint_url( 'custom-tab' ) returns false. Any idea?

Comment: Are you able to run `get_query_var('custom-tab')` to return a value? Try adding the following function and checking to see if it returns as true. Make sure both custom-tab is added to your `query_vars` filter and you have added the tab endpoint via `add_rewrite_endpoint`.

This function should help you determine if you're on your custom tab page.
`function is_custom_tab() {
 global $wp_query;

 if(!isset($wp_query)) {
  return false;
 }
 $tab = get_query_var('custom-tab', false);
 return (is_account_page() && $tab !== false);
}`

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Now working completely. Thanks!

Comment: @Junky   Would be useful if you could provide an answer with the updated code you ended up using, so I can see it :)

Comment: I'll second that @Junky !!